# How to pass the request object on to setup(request, *args, **kwargs) of a FormView through Url

Tags: django

The url:

```
path('signup/', SignUp.as_view()(request), name='signup'),
```

the class whose request attribute i want to initialze with setup :

```
class Login(FormView):
    template_name = 'products_app/login.html'
    form_class = UserLoginForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
```

Comment: Django already initializes the setup with `request`, you can access the request object in a method with `self.request`. But it might make more sense if you specify *what* you aim to do, instead of how (the XY problem).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i wanted to use the request.sessions . thx again man you've helped me a lot. i mean it.